# Should I use block device over char device for reading and writing to memory?

Tags: c, linux, driver

I just started to work in a new company and I'm new in the embedded world.
They gave me a task, I have done it and it's working but I don't know if I did it the right way.
I will describe the task and what I have done.

I was requested to hide some small piece of the DDR from the Linux OS, then some HW feature can write something to this small piece of memory I saved. After that I need to be able to read this small piece of memory to a file.

To hide a chunk of the DDR from the Linux I just changed the Linux memory arg to be equal to the real memory size - (the size I needed + some small size for safety). I have got the idea and the idea for the driver I will describe in a sec from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/how-can-i-reserve-a-block-of-memory-from-the-linux-kernel).
After that the Linux is seeing less memory then the HW has and the top section of the DDR is hided from the kernel and I can use it for my storage without worry.

I think that I have done this part right, not something I can say about the next part.
For the next part, to be able to read this piece of DDR I saved, I wrote a Char device driver, it’s working, it’s reading the DDR chunk I saved to a file piece by piece, every piece is of size no more then some value I decided, can't do it in one copy because it will require allocating a big buffer and I don’t have enough RAM space for that.

Now I read about block device and I started to think that maybe block device fits better for my program, but I'm not relay sure because first it's working and if it's not broken... second I never wrote block device driver, I also never wrote char device driver until the one I described before, so I don't sure if this is the time to use block device over char device.

Comment: Will you be using it more like a file or like a ramdisk?

Comment: It depends how you're intending to use the chunk of RAM. If you're going to treat it like a stream of bytes (i.e. a file or a TCP connection) then you'd use a character device. If you want to use it as bulk storage and mount a filesystem on top of it, then it would be better to implement a block device. Or you could implement both and let the users decide!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answers. I'm treating my chunk of RAM as a stream of bytes, from your answers and Leo answer I'm guessing that I have done the right thing and I should stick with my Char device implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the intended use, but according to your description a character device is much more likely to be what you want. The difference:

a character device takes simple read and write commands and gets no help from the kernel. This is suitable for reading or writing from devices (and from anything that resembles a device, both if it is an actual stream that's read sequentially or supports 'seek' and can read the same data over and over again).

a block device hooks into the kernel's memory paging system and is capable of serving as a back-end for virtual memory pages. It can host a swap space, be the storage for a file system, etc. It is a much more complex beast than a character device. You need this only for something that stores a **large** amount of data that needs to be accessed by mapping it into the address space of a process (normally this is needed only if you put a file system on it).

Comment: Hi Leo. Thank you for the Answer and explanations. So from your answer I'm learning that I have done the right thing. I will stick with my current  implementation.